# How can we install google-chrome-stable on alpine image in dockerfile using dpkg?

Tags: docker, google-chrome, docker-compose, alpine-linux

I am trying to install google-chrome-stable on alpine image using dpkg. However, the dpkg is installed but it does not install google-chrome-stable and return this error instead? Is there a way to install google-chrome-stable in alpine image either using dpkg or other way?

```
dpkg: regarding google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb containing 

google-chrome-stable:amd64, pre-dependency problem:
 google-chrome-stable:amd64 pre-depends on dpkg (>= 1.14.0)

dpkg: error processing archive google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb (--install):
 pre-dependency problem - not installing google-chrome-stable:amd64
Errors were encountered while processing:
```

Dockerfile:

```
# Base image
FROM ruby:2.6.3-alpine3.10
# Use node version 10.16.3, yarn version 1.16.0
RUN apk add  --no-cache --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.10/main/ nodejs=10.16.3-r0
RUN apk add  --no-cache --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.10/community/ yarn=1.16.0-r0

# Install dependencies
RUN apk upgrade
RUN apk --update \
    add build-base \
    git \
    tzdata \
    nodejs \
    nodejs-npm \
    bash \
    curl \
    yarn \
    gzip \
    postgresql-client \
    postgresql-dev \
    imagemagick \
    imagemagick-dev \
    imagemagick-libs \
    chromium \
    chromium-chromedriver \
    ncurses \
    less \
    dpkg=1.19.7-r0 \
    chromium \
    chromium-chromedriver

RUN dpkg --add-architecture amd64
RUN wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
RUN dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

# This is the base directory used in any
# further COPY, RUN and ENTRYPOINT commands
WORKDIR /webapp
# Copy Gemfile and Gemfile.lock and run bundle install
COPY Gemfile* /webapp/
RUN gem install bundler -v '1.17.3' && \
    bundle _1.17.3_ install

# Copy everything to /webapp for docker image
COPY . ./

EXPOSE 3000

# Run the application
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

Answer (score 39):

Installing the Chrome .deb file this way won't work on Alpine.

While the [`dpkg`](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.10/main/aarch64/dpkg) package is available in the Alpine repository, and is useful for installing lightweight Debian packages, you won't be able to use it for installing complex Debian packages, since it'll be impossible to satisfy many Debian dependencies. Alpine is generally not Debian compatible (relying on [musl libc](https://www.musl-libc.org/)), so installing native Alpine packages using apk is the right way to go.

AFAIK, there's currently no Google Chrome Alpine Linux compatible, musl-libc build.

You could, however, install the [Chromium](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.10/community/x86_64/chromium) browser, which is available  using an [apk](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux_package_management) package:

`apk add chromium`

Another option is enabling glibc on a vanilla Alpine image, making it compatible with Debian binaries. This is a fairly simple procedure, see: [Dockerfile](https://github.com/shaharv/docker/blob/master/alpine/glibc/Dockerfile). However, it may not be suitable for images with existing applications such as `ruby:2.6.3-alpine3.10`. Moreover, even with a glibc setup on Alpine, Chrome is not likely to run without issues. I have made a quick attempt ([Dockerfile](https://github.com/shaharv/docker/blob/master/alpine/google-chrome/Dockerfile)) but couldn't get past the first segfault.

**Edit 9/5/21**: Running the debian compatible Chrome stable on Alpine is going to be a very difficult task to say the least. This is in part due to the very large number of dependencies and libraries. Trying to run it results with segfaults during dynamic linking and finally assertions from the dynamic linker. Even if we manage to get passed these issues and start Chrome it will probably be very unstable.

Comment: how to i get stable version of chromium?

Comment: If not Chrome, any way to get an updated build of Chromium?  The package for Alpine is out of date.

Comment: Thanks @Brad! Best bet is building Chromium from source, relying on the [APKBUILD](https://git.alpinelinux.org/aports/tree/community/chromium/APKBUILD) and [package build log](https://build.alpinelinux.org/buildlogs/build-edge-x86_64/community/chromium/chromium-92.0.4515.159-r0.log). This also involves considerable work. I hope to give it a try soon.

Comment: @Brad another option for latest Chromium on Alpine is trying to get a hold of pre-built statically linked Chromium binary. Such binary should be compatible with any Linux since it should carry no dynamic dependencies. I have searched for such a static / monolithic Chromium binary, but without luck so far. In theory such binary could be built on Ubuntu, which is probably better supported, and then run on Alpine.

Comment: @valiano That was the first thing I tried, but unfortunately the architecture type for the binary doesn't match what I can use under Alpine, and is therefore not executable.  Do you know of a fix for that?

Comment: @Brad Interesting. If you're running on standard x86_64, perhaps there's a 32-bit / 64-bit arch mismatch? You could check the executable type using the `file` command and verify it matches the host arch. Are you using publicly available Chrome/Chromium binaries?

Comment: RUN apk --update --upgrade add chromium THEN do this

ENV PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH /usr/bin/chromium-browser

Comment: how about doing multi-stage on the Dockerfile? The first base image is installing the chrome deb, and then copy the image to the second base image which is the ecr.aws/lambda image? Are the google is going to be working?