# Installing google-chrome-stable on Alpine Linux

Tags: docker, google-chrome, alpine-linux

I'm looking to install google-chrome-stable on Alpine Linux.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: I found in this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58654309/how-can-we-install-google-chrome-stable-on-alpine-image-in-dockerfile-using-dpkg) that you can use: `apk add chromium`

Comment: Maybe that help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58654309/how-can-we-install-google-chrome-stable-on-alpine-image-in-dockerfile-using-dpkg