# Running E2E tests with gitlab-runner's docker executor crashes with spawn chromedriver ENOENT error

Tags: google-chrome, protractor, gitlab-ci-runner, e2e

I have an e2e tests project in protractor (v7) with chrome set as the target browser in the **config.ts**

```
...
directConnect: true,
multiCapabilities: [
    {
      browserName: 'chrome',
      chromeOptions: {
        args: ["--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1920x1080", "--no-sandbox"]
      }
    }
],
...
```

Running the project via gitlab-runner's shell executor with `gitlab-runner exec shell run_tests` works fine but if i run it via gitlab-runner's docker executor, with `gitlab-runner exec docker run_tests`, it crashes on the `yarn test` cmd (which basically translates to `protractor config.ts`) of the gitlab-ci script with the following logs:

```
protractor config.ts
[09:14:27] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[09:14:27] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[09:14:27] E/launcher - spawn /builds/project-0/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_90.0.4430.24 ENOENT
[09:14:27] E/launcher - Error: spawn /builds/project-0/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_90.0.4430.24 ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:249:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:442:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:9)
[09:14:27] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
error Command failed with exit code 199.
```

The **.gitlab-ci.yml** looks like this:

```
image: node:12.2.0-alpine

stages:
  - run

variables:
  SERVER_URL: "https://xyz.io/login"
  USER_1_USERNAME: "rico"

run_tests:
  stage: run
  script:
    - echo $SERVER_URL
    - echo $USER_1_USERNAME
    - yarn install:deps
    - yarn test
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Am i missing chrome installation in the ci script ?

Answer (score 0):

So, my hunch was right, it was basically missing google chrome installation and since i was using an alpine docker image, installing chrome was [no simple feat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58654309/how-can-we-install-google-chrome-stable-on-alpine-image-in-dockerfile-using-dpkg) either. So, i had to change my docker image to `node:<version>` which are debian based images and include chrome installation instructions, using info from https://askubuntu.com/a/196100/1217294, only excluding the `sudo`s (they are not needed in a gitlab-runner container) and including and `-y` (to bypass user prompt) after apt-get install, and it worked. Here is how my gitlab ci script looks like:

```
image: node:12

stages:
  - run

run_tests:
  stage: run
  script:
    - wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - 
    - sh -c 'echo "deb https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable
    - yarn install:deps
    - yarn test
```